# Django - The current URL, , didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin

#urlpatterns = [
#    url(r'^mypage/', include('mypage.urls')),
#    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
#]


urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'mypage.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
)
```

The uncommented code is working fine. But as per tutorials the commented code also should have to work. But its showng an error of "The current url didnt match any of these". The code path is /ownblog/ownblog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'views.home', name='home'),
)
```

The above code is in ownblog/mypage/urls.py

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

The above code is in ownblog/mypage/views.py
What I am missing

Comment: And requested what url to get the error message? Because if you requested `/`, the commented patterns don't include a pattern for the root page, only patterns for `/admin/*` and `/mypage/*`.

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in ownblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^mypage/
    ^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

Comment: The commented code does not define a route for the empty URL. If you try with `/mypage` you might get a result. If the tutorial says that the root url is supposed to be handled by the commented code, the tutorial is wrong.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/            The tutorial is from the official website of django

Comment: You haven't defined a url pattern for `/` in your commented code, so it's not surprising that you get that message. The tutorial tells you to go to `http://localhost:8000/polls/`. In your case, change that to `http://localhost:8000/mypage/` because you use `mypage` instead of `polls`.

Comment: Not working still

ImportError at /mypage

No module named views

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/mypage
Django Version:  1.9.5
Exception Type:  ImportError
Exception Value:  

No module named views

Exception Location:  /usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 37
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:  2.7.5
Python Path:  

['/home/ravi/python/ownblog',
 '/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/li

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error message when you visit `http://localhost:8000/` is expected, because you haven't defined a url pattern for / in your commented code. The tutorial tells you to go to `http://localhost:8000/polls/`. In your case, change that to `http://localhost:8000/mypage/` because you use `mypage` instead of `polls`.

The second error `No module named views` is because you have used the string `'views.home'` in your url patterns instead of the callable `views.home`. Make sure you include the import as well.

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

I notice that you are not following the [1.9 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) very closely. For example you are using `patterns()` and strings like `'mypage.views.home'`, which are both outdated since Django 1.8. I think you'd find it useful to follow the tutorial exactly before you begin changing lots of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

new features in django requires a new solutions...

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from polls.views import urls

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^polls/$', urls),
]
```

type in your browser, tested in django 1.10

http://localhost:8000/polls/

Please download a working "HelloWorld" example in django 1.10

https://mega.nz/#!qFsgBbRD!lAKKprkMLmhJcaZ8h5NPxkZcfQpB8qrh1nU4rSSaRAo

Answer (score 0):

You can just see the commented lines by django above your urlpatterns in the urls.py file.

There will be a pattern of setting the path of the url you want to import, you can copy paste that and change the attributes according to the name of your views.

I saying this because the urlpatterns vary from version to version so to write url according to your django version you can refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just the error with your syntax.
Maybe you are following an old tutorial.
Try this one:

```
url(r'^$',views.home,name='home')
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, try this (not recommended personally; I still have some doubt in this region):

```
from django.urls import path
from mypage(appName) import views
...
urlpatterns = [
       path(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
       path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This worked in my case once, but I'm still not sure why!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking at old tutorial, try this one

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from polls<your_app> import views


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

from django.conf.urls import url, include

Change:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('polls', include('polls.urls')),
```

To

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I've also gone through this issue. Sometimes your browser fails to load the page due to launching problem(from the IDE/Code Editor side) so, simply if you do **Empty Cache and Hard Reload in your browser** and then re-run the command then it'll work perfectly.