# Page 404 when Django project WSGIScriptAlias is not /

Tags: django, apache

I am learning Django. I am on Python 3.12.2, Django 5.0.3, Apache HTTPD 2.4.58, Windows 11. I have just done `startproject` (no `startapp` yet). Here is my current directory structure:

```
D:\dev\htdocs                 # Apache HTTPD DocumentRoot
├───...                       # Other directories
│
└───nutrihub_pyvenv           # venv container for Django project
    ├───.venv                 # I use pipenv
    │
    └───nutrihub
        │   db.sqlite3
        │   manage.py
        │   Pipfile
        │   Pipfile.lock
        │
        └───nutrihub
                asgi.py
                settings.py
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
                __init__.py
```

Here is my Apache config:

```
LoadFile "c:/Python312/python312.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "d:/dev/htdocs/nutrihub_pyvenv/.venv/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp312-win_amd64.pyd"
    
WSGIScriptAlias /nhub "d:/dev/htdocs/nutrihub_pyvenv/nutrihub/nutrihub/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonHome "d:/dev/htdocs/nutrihub_pyvenv/.venv"
WSGIPythonPath "d:/dev/htdocs/nutrihub_pyvenv/nutrihub;"
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
<Directory "d:/dev/htdocs/nutrihub_pyvenv/nutrihub/">
  <Files "wsgi.py">
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

`D:\dev\htdocs\nutrihub_pyvenv\nutrihub\nutrihub\settings.py` looks like (only showing few values):

```py
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

When I run the following command:

```
D:\dev\htdocs\nutrihub_pyvenv\nutrihub
(.venv) λ py manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
March 26, 2024 - 06:56:13
Django version 5.0.3, using settings 'nutrihub.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

... I see the page with `The install worked successfully! Congratulations! You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs.` message at `http://localhost:8000/`.
But on starting my Apache HTTPD and going to `http://localhost/nhub`, I see a message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL   : http://localhost/nhub/

Using the URLconf defined in nutrihub.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:    
    admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

However, when I change `WSGIScriptAlias` (everything else no change):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "d:/dev/htdocs/nutrihub_pyvenv/nutrihub/nutrihub/wsgi.py"
```

... and go to `http://localhost`, I see the success message.

I would like to know what I am missing when I give `WSGIScriptAlias` as `/nhub`.

This question is not a duplicate of [Django - The current URL, , didn't match any of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743537/django-the-current-url-didnt-match-any-of-these) as was suggested by SO, as this question and answer compares why with different WSGIScriptAlias the results are different. I already found the answer and have documented it for someone learning Django in future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Django handles `/` in a special manner.

My project's `urls.py` (at `d:/dev/htdocs/nutrihub_pyvenv/nutrihub/nutrihub/urls.py`) by default looks like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Note that there is no path for `''`.

When Django raises Http404 exception, `d:/dev/htdocs/nitrihub_pyvenv/.venv/Lib/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py` => `def response_for_exception` is called, which in turn calls `d:/dev/htdocs/nitrihub_pyvenv/.venv/Lib/site-packages/django/views/debug.py` => `def technical_404_response` if `settings.DEBUG` is true.

In `debug.technical_404_response()`, the following code exists;

```py
if not tried or (  # empty URLconf
    request.path == "/"             # This causes `/` to show Django default
                                    # page, but fails when WSGIScriptAlias is
                                    # set to anything except `/`.
    and len(tried) == 1
    and len(tried[0]) == 1  # default URLconf
    and getattr(tried[0][0], "app_name", "")
    == getattr(tried[0][0], "namespace", "")
    == "admin"
):
    return default_urlconf(request) # The default Django page with Success message
```

The solution to fix this was to update `urls.py` as follows:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views import debug        # Fix

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', debug.default_urlconf),  # Fix
]
```

This is only a temporary fix as I will need to the project home once I add some Django apps to it, after which I will update `path('', ...)`.

Thanks to [Who generates the default page of django welcome page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951468/who-generates-the-default-page-of-django-welcome-page) for clues to what was going on.